# Create a counter_cache that only counts records with a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

A "user" has many "posts".  I want to create a counter_cache in "users" that shows how many posts they have.

This is straightforward to do - but I only want posts to be counted in the counter_cache if they are public (i.e `post.is_public === true`).

How can I create a column in the users table that has their total number of public posts?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  // Columns:   id:integer   name:string
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  // Columns:  id:integer   user_id:integer   is_public:boolean   content:text

  belongs_to :user, dependent :destroy, counter_cache: true
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counter Cache for a column with conditions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347323/counter-cache-for-a-column-with-conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to update that counter_cache with update, you could use ActiveRecord callbacks: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html. Then you can use conditional either in callback declaration:

```
before_save :counter_cache, if: proc { |r| r.public }
```

OR you could have that conditional inside counter_cache method itself, if it knows of record. Otherwise you can just use line above.

Also, it's more idiomatic (and clean) to just use `post.is_public`, than to compare it stricty against true just like you don't say `if a > 3 === true`

Answer (score 0):

first you need to make association in the user model and post model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

make column name as counter_cache using following command

```
 rail g migration add_counter_cache_to_users post:references
```

now user id is in post table, and you can get the number of post of the user in the controller by
first check for public post

```
 if post.is_public === true
 User_Record = User.first
 id= User_record.id
 user_Post=Post.where(:user_id=>id)
 end
```

you will get the post of your user on the basis of user id