# counter_cache in Rails on a scoped association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, named-scope, counter-cache

I have `User` model which `has_many :notifications`. `Notification` has a boolean column `seen` and a scope called `:unseen` which returns all notifications where `seen` is `false`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :unseen_notifications, -> { unseen }, class_name: "Notification"
end
```

I know that I can cache the number of *notifications* if I add a column called `notifications_count` to `users` and add `counter_cache: true` to my `belongs_to` call in `Notification`.

But what if I want to cache the number of *unseen* notifications a user has? I.e. cache `unseen_notifications.size` instead of `notifications.size`? Is there a built-in way to do this with `counter_cache` or do I have to roll my own solution?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no built-in way to do this. But you can try [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem. It might fit your needs

Answer (score 7):

According to [this blog post](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/19/activerecords-counter-cache.html#scoped-associations), there is no built-in way to use counter caches for scoped associations:

> ActiveRecord’s counter cache callbacks only fire when creating or destroying records, so adding a counter cache on a scoped association won’t work. For advanced cases, like only counting the number of *published* responses, check out the [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem.

Other than using an external gem, you could roll your own solution by adding callbacks to your `Notification` model and adding an integer column (e.g., `unseen_notifications_count`) to the `User` model:

```rb
# Notification.rb
after_save    :update_counter_cache
after_destroy :update_counter_cache

def update_counter_cache
  self.user.unseen_notifications_count = self.user.unseen_notifications.size
  self.user.save
end
```

Also see the answers to [Counter Cache for a column with conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347323/counter-cache-for-a-column-with-conditions) for additional implementation examples of this approach.