# Rails counter cache with condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, counter-cache

I have a rails hotel application which has rooms inside it. Rooms can have n number of tickets associated to them. I have create a counter cache with counter culture gem which updates the room table with number of tickets assigned to it,
the problem is i only want count of tickets which are open or in progress state. I have this code it works fine normally but does not work with the condition can anyone guide me by letting me know how can i work it with conditions? Any help is appreciated

Room Table Migration file

```
 class AddTicketsCountToRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def self.up
      add_column :rooms, :tickets_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
    end
  end
```

Ticket.rb file

```
    belongs_to :room
  counter_culture :room, column_name: proc {|model| model.status? [0,1] 'tickets_count' : nil }
```

This does not go according to the where clause and 
gives me error saying

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting '}' {|model| model.status? [0,1] 'tickets_count' : nil } ^ /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/app/models/ticket.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end tatus? [0,1] 'tickets_count' : nil }
```

Answer (score 10):

Rails does not provide conditions with counter_cache. `where` clause and `each` is not going to work either.

To achieve conditional counter, you can use custom callbacks in your code to manage counter [blog on custom counter_cache with conditions](https://douglasfshearer.com/2006/10/06/custom-counter-cache-with-conditions.html).

Alternatively, you can use [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem, [conditional-counter-cache](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture#conditional-counter-cache)

please refer answers on similar question -
[Counter Cache for a column with conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347323/counter-cache-for-a-column-with-conditions)

Comment: i worked with the counter_culture gem but the conditions isnt working i followed the step in the link and have something as counter_culture :room, column_name: proc {|model| model.status? [0,1] 'tickets_count' : nil } but it gives me an error saying syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' :room, column_name: proc {|model| model.status? [0,1 @tahahussain, i have even edited my question accordingly

Comment: @MohammedSayer looks like there's a syntax error in ternary condition you are using in proc. Please modify your proc as `counter_culture :room, column_name: proc {|model| model.status.in?([0,1]) ? 'tickets_count' : nil }`